# ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy Scheme Setting for WandB NOT Compatible with OpenAI API

Tags: proxy, openai-api, wandb

#### Describe the bug

In WSL Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I use the following proxy setting so that I can get to OpenAI and pips behind the proxy.
If I add any `http` or `https` schema like `export HTTPS_PROXY="http://192.168.10.166:11111/"`, the OpenAI API and pip installs will not work.
Is there anyway to compromise the proxy settings, eg. adding compatibles in the codes?

```bash
export http_proxy="192.168.10.166:11111"
export https_proxy="192.168.10.166:11111"
export ALL_PROXY="192.168.10.166:11111"
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,192.168.*.*,10.0.*.*"
```

When I run this code I get error of `ProxySchemeUnknown`.

```py
from langchain.callbacks import WandbCallbackHandler, StdOutCallbackHandler
from datetime import datetime

session_group = datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%Y_%H.%M.%S")
wandb_callback = WandbCallbackHandler(
    job_type="inference",
    project="langchain_callback_demo",
    group=f"minimal_{session_group}",
    name="llm",
    tags=["test"],
)
callbacks = [StdOutCallbackHandler(), wandb_callback]
```

```bash
File [~/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py:481](https://vscode-remote+wsl-002bubuntu-002d22-002e04.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/home/ocean/projects/behavior/~/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py:481), in ProxyManager.__init__(self, proxy_url, num_pools, headers, proxy_headers, proxy_ssl_context, use_forwarding_for_https, **connection_pool_kw)
    478 proxy = parse_url(proxy_url)
    480 if proxy.scheme not in ("http", "https"):
--> 481     raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
    483 if not proxy.port:
    484     port = port_by_scheme.get(proxy.scheme, 80)
ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

In cmd line interface, when I type wandb, I also get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/bin/wandb", line 5, in <module>
    from wandb.cli.cli import cli
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wandb/__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    _sentry.setup()
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wandb/analytics/sentry.py", line 40, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wandb/analytics/sentry.py", line 76, in setup
    client = sentry_sdk.Client(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/client.py", line 143, in __init__
    self._init_impl()
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/client.py", line 211, in _init_impl
    self.transport = make_transport(self.options)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/transport.py", line 534, in make_transport
    return transport_cls(options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/transport.py", line 154, in __init__
    self._pool = self._make_pool(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sentry_sdk/transport.py", line 444, in _make_pool
    return urllib3.ProxyManager(proxy, **opts)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 481, in __init__
    raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
urllib3.exceptions.ProxySchemeUnknown: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <bound method Sentry.end_session of <wandb.analytics.sentry.Sentry object at 0x7ff642be4a10>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wandb/analytics/sentry.py", line 40, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ocean/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wandb/analytics/sentry.py", line 163, in end_session
    assert self.hub is not None
AssertionError:
```

#### Environment

WandB version: 0.15.3
Langchain version: 0.0.172
OS: WSL Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS,
Python version: 3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

**This PARTIALLY solve my problem at last. But not sure if any other nasty things will happen because I changed some package code. I would like to learn from others about a cleaner method.**

I temporarily changed the urllib3's poolmanager code to deprecate the error. But not sure if any other nasty things will happen. In my env, `/home/username/miniconda3/envs/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py`,
At the start of the code file I added necessary import in between `### Manually Changed for WandB ###`:

```py
...
from .util.retry import Retry
from .util.url import parse_url

### Manually Changed for WandB ###
from .util.url import Url
### Manually Changed for WandB ###

__all__ = ["PoolManager", "ProxyManager", "proxy_from_url"]
...
```

Around line 480, I changed code as following between `### Manually Chaged for WandB ###`:

```py
...
        if isinstance(proxy_url, HTTPConnectionPool):
            proxy_url = "%s://%s:%i" % (
                proxy_url.scheme,
                proxy_url.host,
                proxy_url.port,
            )
        proxy = parse_url(proxy_url)

        if proxy.scheme not in ("http", "https"):
            ### Manually Changed for WandB ###
            proxy = Url(scheme="https", host=proxy.host, port=proxy.port, path=proxy.path)
            # raise ProxySchemeUnknown(proxy.scheme)
            ### Manually Changed for WandB ###

        if not proxy.port:
            port = port_by_scheme.get(proxy.scheme, 80)
            proxy = proxy._replace(port=port)

...
```